# How to use `reveal-code-focus` within `org-mode` in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, reveal.js

I would like to use `reveal-code-focus` within `org-mode` in Emacs (https://bnjmnt4n.github.io/reveal-code-focus/#/reveal-code-focus). Is there an example that someone could walk me through on how to do it? I have looked and looked but not found any help.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
   import random
   random.seed(1)
   print("Hello World! Here's a random number: %f" % random.random()) 
#+END_SRC
```

In the above example I want the background color for random.seed(1) to be highlighted when exporting to HTML using reveal.js.

Please note that, it is not for syntax highlighting but for code focus.

Comment: The question is too broad. SO is not a site where you ask for a user manual or in-depth tutorial. Please consider identifying a specific problem/question.

Comment: #+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
  import random
  random.seed(1)
  print("Hello World! Here's a random number: %f" % random.random())
#+END_SRC

In this example I want the background color for  random.seed(1) to be highlighted when exporting to HTML using reveal.js

Comment: Please edit your question to say what you put in the comment, if that's the question you want to ask. Comments can be deleted at any time.